# Finding the set of equations orthogonal to parabolas

Tags: calculus

The problem is to find the set of equations $\mathcal{G}$ where every equation in $\mathcal{G}$ is perpendicular to every equation in $\mathcal{F}$, where $\mathcal{F}$ consists of equations of the form $y = Ax$.

By plotting, I guessed that $\mathcal{G}$ will be the set of circles around the origin:

Plot: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zazva0jlzo

How can I express the slope of this series at $(x,y)$? I tried using $A = y^2/x$, but this gives me $\mathcal{G} = \frac{x^3}3$.

From there I know to take the negative reciprical of the slope and solve the differential equation.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Are you looking for the set of curves orthogonal to every parabola of the form $y^2=Ax$? If so, I guess the intro about orthogonal curves to rays emanating from a common point is quite irrelevant.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio yes, I need to find the set of curves where every individual curve is orthogonal to each one in the other set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what exactly you want.

Instead of downvoting I would give a lead as a take off point for OT of parabolas $ y= A x^2$

If you carefully see desmos graph you made.. the extreme parabola cuts at around $70^0$, but not at $90^0.$

Now for parabola OT:

$$ y = A x^2 $$

$$ y^{'}= 2 A x $$

Eliminate $A$

$$\frac{2y}{x^2} =  \frac{y^{'}}{x} $$

$$\frac{2y}{x} =  \frac{y^{'}}{1} $$

negative reciprocal for OT's differential equation

$$\frac{2y}{x} =  \frac{{-1}}{y^{'}} $$

integrate and simplify

$$ -2 y dy = x dx$$

$$ x^2/2 + y^2 = c^2 $$

They are all ellipses of eccentricity $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt2}$. The other  $y = - A x^2$ below $x-$ axis not sketched.

Basically you addressed the problem, but going in different directions.. as it appears to me.

This way, now if you ask questions in the comments we will go somewhere..hopefully.

[image: OT parabolas]

Comment: Thank you, I see how to get the problem now. The desmos graph is actually 90 degrees though, click on default zoom (home icon). I could not figure out  how to change the zoom window.

Comment: Watch this lecture, where it is explained: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01-single-variable-calculus-fall-2006/video-lectures/lecture-16-differential-equations/